# (SOLVED) Saving Configuration result in `java.lang.Throwable: HttpInput idle timeout`

Tags: jenkins

When adding a new `Item` or saving an existing `Item's` Configuration the following Error appears. The Jenkins System runs as a Service on a Windows 2019 VM. The Version of the installed Jenkins is `2.222.3`.

There is no difference which kind of Project Type I use ( Freestyle, Pipeline, etc. ).

### Repro Steps

- Create new Item ( Freestyle )
- Click `Save` `>>` Error appears

### Error

```
 Oops!
A problem occurred while processing the request. Please check our bug tracker to
 see if a similar problem has already been reported. If it is already reported, 
please vote and put a comment on it to let us gauge the impact of the problem. If 
you think this is a new issue, please file a new issue. When you file an issue,
 make sure to add the entire stack trace, along with the version of Jenkins and 
relevant plugins. The users list might be also useful in understanding what has 
happened.

Stack trace
Also:   java.lang.Throwable: HttpInput idle timeout
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput.onIdleTimeout(HttpInput.java:801)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelOverHttp.onIdleTimeout(HttpChannelOverHttp.java:406)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onReadTimeout(HttpConnection.java:495)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection.onFillInterestedFailed(AbstractConnection.java:172)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillInterestedFailed(HttpConnection.java:502)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.failed(AbstractConnection.java:317)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.onFail(FillInterest.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.onIdleExpired(AbstractEndPoint.java:407)
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 5000/5000 ms
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.idleCheck(IdleTimeout.java:113)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
Caused: java.io.IOException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput$ErrorState.noContent(HttpInput.java:1083)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput.read(HttpInput.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput.read(HttpInput.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoded.decodeUtf8To(UrlEncoded.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoded.decodeTo(UrlEncoded.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractFormParameters(Request.java:568)
Caused: org.eclipse.jetty.io.RuntimeIOException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractFormParameters(Request.java:573)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractContentParameters(Request.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameters(Request.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameterNames(Request.java:1077)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.extractCrumbFromRequest(CrumbFilter.java:166)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at jenkins.security.SuspiciousRequestFilter.doFilter(SuspiciousRequestFilter.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1300)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1580)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.run(HttpChannel.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

### Solution

It was a Network Issue. Needed to reconnect the VPN Connection between the Client and the Jenkins VM. Not sure why some Network Tasks work, like accessing Jenkins and others don't.